# How does a git merge deal with common commits?

Tags: git

In the Git documentation, Git rebase specifies when there is a common commit, this common commit is skipped:

> If the upstream branch already contains a change you have made (e.g.,
>   because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that
>   commit will be skipped. For example, running ‘git rebase master` on
>   the following history (in which A’ and A introduce the same set of
>   changes, but have different committer information):

And to visualize it:

```
          A---B---C topic
         /
    D---E---A'---F master
```

becomes:

```
                   B'---C' topic
                  /
    D---E---A'---F master
```

My question is: What happens in this situation when you are doing a merge instead of a rebase?

Edit: And more importantly... is commit A done once or twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will become,

```
      A---B---C      topic
     /          \
D---E---A'---F -- F'    master
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

it says `Except in a fast-forward merge (see above), the branches to be merged must be tied together by a merge commit that has both of them as its parents.` Clearly this is not a ff.

Comment: Im revising my question/comment. Earlier I said that commit 'A' was done twice but now I have reason to believe it is only done once, which would be more efficient anyway. @JakubNarębski I never heard of imerge..what are the benefits?

Comment: @user2202911: **git-imerge** (https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) is a tool to do *incremental* large merge or large rebase by the way of automatically doing merge of all commits on both branches (cross product of branches), so I guess it would pick that A' and A are about the same change.  See e.g. http://softwareswirl.blogspot.com/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html